# Reduce flat array to 2-level nested json object array

Tags: javascript, json, nested, reduce

I have the following flat array:

```
{ "State": "New York", "Name": "Jane", "Product": "Apple" },
{ "State": "New York", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"},
{ "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Apple" },
{ "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"}
```

Is it possible to create a 2-level nested array (i.e., Name > nested State Array > nested Product Array)?  It would look like as follows:

```
{
  "Name": "Jill",
  "States": [
   {
   "State": "California",
   "Products": [
      {
    "Product": "Apple"
      },
      {
          "Product": "Banana"
      }
    ]
   },
   {
   "State": "New York",
   "Products": [
      {
          "Product": "Banana"
      }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "Name": "Jane",
  "States": [
   {
   "State": "New York",
   "Products": [
     {
      "Product": "Apple"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

I have been able to get one level nested (States).  How would you nest the second level?

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lu6zj2

```
this.grouped_data = this.data.reduce((data, item) => {
  data[item.Name] = data[item.Name] || { Name: item.Name, States: []}
  data[item.Name].States.push(item) 
  return data;
}, {})
```

Comment: I have edited the tags as it's not a question related to Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  { "State": "New York", "Name": "Jane", "Product": "Apple" },
  { "State": "New York", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"},
  { "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Apple" },
  { "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"}
];

let grouped = data.reduce((p, n) => {
  // Create the Lady
  if (!p[n.Name]) p[n.Name] = { States: [] };
  // Check if the state exists, if not create it, then push product into it
  if (!p[n.Name].States.some(state => state.State === n.State)) {
    p[n.Name].States.push({ State: n.State, Products: [n.Product] });
  } else {
    !p[n.Name].States.find(state => state.State === n.State).Products.push(n.Product);
  }
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

After that you can also remove duplicated products if you want to. I'll let you deal with it !

**EDIT** I didn't respect your model, what a dumbass am I ... Here it is :

```js
let data = [
  { "State": "New York", "Name": "Jane", "Product": "Apple" },
  { "State": "New York", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"},
  { "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Apple" },
  { "State": "California", "Name": "Jill", "Product": "Banana"}
];

let grouped = data.reduce((p, n) => {
  // Create the Lady
  if (!p.some(lady => lady.Name === n.Name)) p.push({ Name: n.Name, States: [] });
  let lady = p.find(lady => lady.Name === n.Name);
  // Check if the state exists, if not create it, then push product into it
  if (!lady.States.some(state => state.State === n.State)) {
    lady.States.push({ State: n.State, Products: [n.Product] });
  } else {
    lady.States.find(state => state.State === n.State).Products.push(n.Product);
  }
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: I think you could put `p[n.Name].States.find(state => state.State === n.State)` to a variable and check if it is undefined in `if`. Now, `some` and `find` are traversing the array with the same condition

Comment: @adiga but if I do that and it's undefined I can't use the memory reference afterwards

Comment: Something like this: `let found = p[n.Name].States.find(state => state.State === n.State); if(!found) { p[n.Name].States.push(...) } else { found.Products.push(n.Product) }`

Comment: This works great, thanks! @adiga I'm getting same error as Maryannah with the p[n.Name].States.find...  Maybe I'm doing that wrong?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3u7tjs

Comment: @user749798 his/her issue with my answer is only about the performance on huge datasets. What error are you having exactly ?

Comment: @Maryannah Your answer works great for your answer.   Was wondering where adiga was going, but it's not needed.  Your answer works well.  Thank you!

Comment: It's just that my complexity in the reduce is about `O(2n)` while it could be `O(n)`, nothing very substantial for that example !

Comment: @user749798 you missed the `if (!p[n.Name]) p[n.Name] = { States: [] };` line inside `reduce` [Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ggftb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)